# IE8 Unable to download files

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, download, internet-explorer-8

I recently installed Windows 7.  I can browse to any webpage using IE8, but if I click on any links to download files, I receive the following error:

> Unable to download [filename] from [website].
>
> Unable to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try again later.

I can download files perfectly fine using firefox, it's just IE that is having issues.

There are no messages in the windows event log.  I have no add-ins installed and have made no security changes as this is a fresh install.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  Did you found anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue.  Maybe it will help you solve your issue.

First, it was cause because I moved my Users folder from c:\Users to d:\Users using an uncompleted method (involving repair from installation dvd and robocopy.) I will put a comment to fix this issue.

I also notice that I was unable to create new favorite.

To solve this issue, you have to take ownership of your user folder:

```
1. Go in Windows explorer
2. RClick on your user folder (ie: d:\Users\admin) and select Properties
3. Go on Security tab and click the Advanced button
4. Select the Owner tab and Click the Edit button
5. Select your account, check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
6. Click OK until you get out of the Properties windows
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if windows can not create the temporary internet files or update the index file, ie if it is read-only.

Try opening a command prompt (ie Start CMD)

and type

```
attrib    "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\INDEX.DAT"
```

This should show the filename and the attributes which are normally SH, but could include R (for readonly). If so you can correct this using the command

```
attrib -r "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\INDEX.DAT"
```

If the attrib command gives an error, then check the directory (specified in Internet Options, General, Browsing History, Settings, current location) actually exists

Comment: I verified that the attribute settings are correct.  I can browse the web just fine.  It's only when I try to download a file.